# Query flat data firebase, angularfire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have data stored in firebase in the following structure (figure 1). I followed the guidelines for structuring data and saved it in a flat structure with key-val pairs on events and users to allow for a many to many relationship reference. I want to user a userid to look up events that a user has access to, in pure javascript this is simple (see figure 2) however it is proving difficult with angularfire as I'd like to use a firebaseObject or array. Does anyone know how to perform a query like this?

**Figure 1.**

```
{
  users: {
      user_id1: {
         events: {
            event_id1: true,
            event_id2: true
         }
      },
      user_id2: {
         events: {
            event_id3: true,
            event_id4: true
         }
      },
      user_idN...
  },
  events: {
    event_id1: {
        users: {
           user_id1: true
         }
    },
    event_id2: {
        users: {
           user_id1: true
         }
    },
    event_idN...
  }
}
```

**Figure 2**

```
// List all of user_id1's events
var ref = new Firebase("https://<<example>>.firebaseio.com/");
// fetch a list of user_id1's events
ref.child("users/user_id1/events").on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  // for each event, fetch it and print it
  String groupKey = snapshot.key();
  ref.child("events/" + groupKey).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you using angularJS? @anauleau

Comment: Yes, I am using both AngularJs.

Comment: Could you share that code as well. How you using it.

Comment: I'm not using it yet. I don't know how to implement figure 2 utilizing a $firebaseObject. I need to attach it scope.

Comment: Refer to this. this might help you https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html

Comment: I've looked at the docs exhaustively, I don't really understand what to do. Ideally I could define a Ref that I could pass directly to a $firebaseObject but I don't think there is a recipe utilizing their query methods.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a great case for using `$extend` in AngularFire.**

You're sharing the `$event_id` key so can load the events after, the user is retrieved.

```
app.factory("UserFactory", function($firebaseObject) {
  return $firebaseObject.$extend({
      getEvent: function(eventId) {
        var eventRef = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>/events').child(eventId);
        return $firebaseObject(eventRef);
      }
   });
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, UserFactory) {
  var userRef = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>').child("users/user_id1/");
  var user = new UserFactory();
  $scope.event = user.getEvent(user.events.event_id1);
});
```

[**See the API reference for more information.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-creating-angularfire-services)

Comment: Thanks, will test it out later today. I am dealing with multiple events but I assume I can pass each event obj to an array.