# How to merge results of two queries using FirebaseArray

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

How to merge results of two queries using FirebaseArray

I have taken data from firebase

```
$scope.concepts = firebasearray(ref);
```

Have taken data from second firebase query in a similar way.

Both are displaying list.
But second list is showing for the last element and its repeating same for every element of first ref call.

In html

```
<li ng-repeat="(concept) in concepts">
<h3 ng-model="concept.name">{{concept.conceptname}}</h3>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="count in count">
<a ng-href="#/edit/{{concept.$id}}/" target="_blank">Page {{count.id}}</a>
</div>
</li>
```

The firebase structures are:

```
Concept:
 ConceptId
   ConceptName

Content
   ConceptId
      ContentId
          Page id
             Text
```

How can I fetch the page id from another database structure to show with the concept name fetched from another database structure?

Comment: I suppose `concept` is an element from `concepts` array that comes from firebase? and each `concept` also has this `$id` attribute? and lastly what is `(conc)`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire