# How to fetch data from two collections in one query in fire-base db?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

How to fetch 2-3 collections in one go to save multiple data hits suing fire-base and angular-fire?

Comment: A firebase listener can only read data from under one location. So you'll have to do some client-side joining yourself. Read this question to learn [why the multiple requests aren't as slow as you may think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) and [this one for more on client-side joining using AngularFire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire).