# Firebase & Angular - Retrieve and display flattening data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have flattening data in my firebase with the following code. But when I want display favorite user posts list with ng-repeat, the template gets repeated a second time and comes out totally blank. How can I correct this?

```
  "Post": {
    "xKkdfjjfld856i": {
      "name": "My first post",
      "author": "Miguel"
    },
    "xKkdfjj556FGHh": { ... },
    "xK499DF6FlHjih": { ... }
  },
  "users": {

    "John": {
      favorited_posts {
         "xKkdfjjfld856i": true,
         "xKkdfjj556FGHh": true
      }
    },
    "Mia": { ... },
    "Patrick": { ... }
  },
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in favoritedPosts track by $index">
    <div class="card post-card">
       <h1>{{post.name}}</h1>
       <p>{{post.author}}</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Controller :

```
var userRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/users")
var userFavoriteRef = userRef.child($scope.user_id).child("favorited_posts")
var favoritedPosts = $firebaseArray(userFavoriteRef)

userFavoriteRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

    var key = childSnapshot.key();

    var postRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Posts")

    postRef.child(childSnapshot.ref().key()).once('value', function(postSnapshot) {
      console.log("Look",postSnapshot.val());
      $scope.favoritedPosts = postSnapshot.val();
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try working with the `$firebaseArray` and `$getRecord` ([documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey)) to get the object value based on the object key. Then you will have everything you need without looping over assync calls.

### Controller

```
var userRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/users")
var userFavoriteRef = userRef.child($scope.user_id).child("favorited_posts")
$scope.favoritedPosts = $firebaseArray(userFavoriteRef)
var postRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Posts")
$scope.posts = $firebaseArray(postRef)
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="post in favoritedPosts">
        <div class="card post-card">
            <h1>{{posts.$getRecord(post.$id).name}}</h1>
            <p>{{posts.$getRecord(post.$id).author}}</p>
        </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It's work like a charm ! You're the best thank you !! :D :D

Comment: @YngDev31 Uw! Really glad u made it :)

Comment: @adolfosrs what if there are thousands posts at post node and you are downloading all posts to client? thats good thing? I dont think so

Comment: @ZaidMirza you are godamn right. To avoid it you would rather prefer to set some query parameters in you call and you also should structure your database in a way it will best perform depending on your needs. :)

Comment: @adolfosrs I found this solution is more applicable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire