# Firebase and Ionic: Best way to return an object in scope

Tags: object, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in Ionic and I have a simple question I think :

Here is my JSON :

```
"profiles" : {
  "wXD7sHme9gSoWXcB799VgzZDDA03" : {
    "uid": "wXD7sHme9gSoWXcB799VgzZDDA03",
    "languesDispo": [0,2]
  }
},
"langues" : {
  "anglais" : {
     "id" : 0
   },
  "allemand": {
    "id" : 1
   },
  "espagnol": {
    "id" : 2,
  }
}
```

I would like to return in scope an object (or array) with all `langues` based on the ids in the `profiles` node at `languesDispo`.

I would like to know what is the best way to do that, what can I use between

- $firebaseArray()
- $firebaseObject()
- ref.on()
- ref.once()
- loaded()

I have to admit I'm a little bit confused. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are you using angularFire or just firebase alone?

Comment: You're trying to join data from two locations. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire) for a good way to do that by one of AngularFire's authors.

Comment: I'm using angularFire.