# Firebase look ups/retrieval of flatten data

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have data structure like below as Firebase suggested it.

```
{
  links: {
    link1: {
      title: "Example",
      href: "http://example.org",
      submitted: "user1",
      comments: {
        comment1: true
        comment2:true
                }
           }
          }
 comments:{
   comment1:{
     text: hi im comment1
            }
   comment2:{
     text:hi im comment 2
            }
         }
}
```

This [Article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) have told how to lookup data structured like this.
but that was pure Firebase SDK related. How we can do lookups in AngularFire?

Sync data to firebase is essential for me. I know `$firebaseArray()` syncs data automatically. But I facing trouble when I need to sync Comments?

Below is code from Controller

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref("links");
        $scope.links = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

and here is my `HTML`

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links">

<p>{{link.title}}</p>
<p>{{link.href}}</p>
<p>{{link.comments}}</p> ////////// how I can get comment from here I have 
                       /////only Ids of comment. how I can get link comment
</div>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have checked,Kato has told two methods, which one is better? `$extend` or `Firebase-util`? is `Firebase util` is officially supported Lib by `Firebase`? and both the methods will support implicit sync?