# AngularJS: weird behavior with the 2-way binding (ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS in a Firebase app and I have a function where I do some inner join to get some data. More [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849551/angularfire-how-to-run-join-queries/41104732#41104732). After getting the response from the firebase api I create an object and push it into an array (a scope variable). I see in the debug that the data has been retrieved and that the $scope variable is filled correctly. The problem is that it is not showing in the ng-repeat.

My function:

```
$scope.getMessagesByRegion = function(regionId){

    console.log('Function start');
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var regionMessagesRef = rootRef.child("region_messages/"+ regionId);
    $scope.messages_by_region = []; // Here I reset the scope variable

    regionMessagesRef.on('child_added', function(rmSnap) {

        var messageRef = rootRef.child("messages/"+rmSnap.key);
        messageRef.once('value').then(function(msgSnap){

            var msg = {
                key : msgSnap.key,
                name : msgSnap.val().name,
                type : $scope.getTypeName(msgSnap.val().type),
                show_only_once : rmSnap.val().show_only_once,
                pre_requisite_message : rmSnap.val().pre_requisite_message
            }
            console.log(msg); // here I see the object in the console. it is OK
            $scope.messages_by_region.push(msg); // pushing the item
            console.log('----------------');
            console.log($scope.messages_by_region);
        })

    });
}
```

My HTML:

```
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Message name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Show only once</th>
                    <th>Pre requisite</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="msg in messages_by_region">
                    <td ng-bind="msg.name"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="msg.type"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="msg.show_only_once"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="msg.pre_requisite_message"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This is what I see in the console:

[image]

The problem is that even having an object in the array it is not shown in the view. It is like there was an empty array set to the `$scope.messages_by_region` variable

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Can you see what's wrong with my function?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try adding the console.log($scope.messages_by_region); to a test function and make a ng-click call this function and see what happens. Also do you see any error in the console?

Comment: did you try without ng-bind directive? `<td>{{msg.name}}</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try,

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
 $scope.messages_by_region.push(msg);
});
```

or,

```
$scope.messages_by_region.push(msg);
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Apply receiving a function so it checks only for the value affected inside that function?

Comment: you calling a non angular function `messageRef.once` therefore you have to tell the angular that some $scope variable changed .

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using async functions (Cosuming of firebase API) you should tell angular to refresh the HTML;

Use

```
$scope.$diggest()
```

More information you can find on https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: Thanks!  I had to use $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 1):

As you are performing Async calls you need to tell angular to refresh the changes in the value with `$apply` call you can do it with:

```
$scope.getMessagesByRegion = function(regionId) {

  console.log('Function start');
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var regionMessagesRef = rootRef.child("region_messages/" + regionId);
  $scope.messages_by_region = []; // Here I reset the scope variable

  regionMessagesRef.on('child_added', function(rmSnap) {

    var messageRef = rootRef.child("messages/" + rmSnap.key);
    messageRef.once('value').then(function(msgSnap) {
        var msg = {
          key: msgSnap.key,
          name: msgSnap.val().name,
          type: $scope.getTypeName(msgSnap.val().type),
          show_only_once: rmSnap.val().show_only_once,
          pre_requisite_message: rmSnap.val().pre_requisite_message
        }

      $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log(msg); // here I see the object in the console. it is OK
        $scope.messages_by_region.push(msg); // pushing the item
        console.log('----------------');
        console.log($scope.messages_by_region);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

For more information on this behavior you can also read article describing the problem [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)